# Please help identify what set this bag belongs to, white windows and fences, and tan circles

Tags: set-identification

[image: 2011 bag]

Bag indicates that it was made in 2011.

Comment: The year printed on the bag typically has more to do with the design/production of *the bag*, than the set it is used for.

Answer (score 3):

This one is definitely from 10214 London Tower Bridge. I only have a used set that didn't have the original bags, but all parts and colors match perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

The [Technic Wedge Belt Wheel (Pulley)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=823#T=C&C=2) only comes in tan in 5 sets and the only one of those sets that has more than 2 (which your bag clearly does) is [10214 Tower Bridge](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=10214-1#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D).